# VBA Pivot Table Range change

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `PivotTable` that it's range and data always changes I have the below data:

```
Range("A3").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
DataArea = "Sheet21!R1C1:R" & Selection.Rows.Count & "C" & Selection.COLUMNS.Count
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataArea, _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
```

I'm getting an error

> Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will modify "PivotTable7" in "Sheet1" (modify to your sheet's name where you have your `PivotTable`), with the `SourceData` from `Worksheets("Sheet21").Range("A3").CurrentRegion`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangePivotTableCache()

Dim PvtTbl  As PivotTable
Dim DataArea As String

' fully qualify your range by adding the worksheet object
With Worksheets("Sheet21").Range("A3").CurrentRegion
    DataArea = "Sheet21!R1C1:R" & .Rows.Count & "C" & .Columns.Count
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable7") '<-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name

On Error GoTo 0
If Not PvtTbl Is Nothing Then ' <-- If pivot table exist
    PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataArea)
Else ' <-- If pivot table doesn't exist
    MsgBox "Pivot Table doesn't exist in worksheet!"
End If

End Sub
```

**Note**: to get the `String` of the `SourceData` you could also use:

```
DataArea = "Sheet21!" & Worksheets("Sheet21").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
```