# VBA create Pivot Table from dinamic source

Tags: vba

I saw similar questions being asked. But I could not find what I need.

I have a sheet, the name of the file and the sheet is variable.

In that sheet there is a table starting from cell A1, the number of columns and rows varies, it is never the same.

I need a macro that creates a PivotTable from this sheet into a brand new sheet with a predefined name, taking into consideration that the number of rows and columns is varying.
The pivot sheet must be created, it can't be in existence prior to creating the pivot

Thank You in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Where is your code attempt ?

Comment: Damn you're fast! @ShaiRado

Comment: Alexandru, please take the [tour] and see [help/on-topic] and [ask]! ;)

Comment: Few similar posts here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599995/error-on-pivot-cache-syntax/42604818#42604818 , and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144495/vba-pivot-table-range-change/42144940#42144940